# google glass, ASM mirroring

Tags: android, adt, google-glass, mirroring

I'm trying to mirroring my google glass to my desktop (Windows 8)
I downloaded `ASM_2_50`

I have tried to place my `adb.exe` under
`adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools`
and
`adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools`
and add the path variable to the `adb.exe` accordinly.
Still, when I'm giving

```
java -jar asm.jar
```

I get the message:

```
could not find adb, please install Android SDK and set path to adb
```

How come?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have the proper build for the ADB. Or maybe don't have it at all. It isn't there by default when you download the standalone SDK.

It's an easy fix. Just go open your SDK manager and update your platform tools/tools/build tools, if they are empty or incomplete. This should fix the issue.

Comment: All my Android SDK tools are installed. I have tools in my menue, but not build. not under tools. How do I update?

Comment: @user3170595 Just make sure that you have the latest tools installed. There is no special "build" option - those are the build tools.